# Xcode 5 crashes when running an app with SDL 2

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode5, sdl, sdl-2

I tried to follow these two tutorials (or the applicable parts of them, due to version differences) to install SDL 2.0.2 to work with Xcode 5.1:

[Tutorial 1](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/)

[Tutorial 2](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/index.php)

Running any program with the SDL 2 framework linked causes Xcode to crash with the following problem details:

```
Process:         Xcode [1787]  
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode  
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode  
Version:         5.1 (5084)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5084000000000000~21
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 444172641
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [257]
Responsible:     Xcode [1787]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
PlugIn Identifier: org.libsdl.SDL2
PlugIn Version:    2.0.2 (2.0.2)

Date/Time:       2014-03-13 04:24:59.771 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  EFECF2A0-A489-055E-0904-D3CD9E756EB0


Crashed Thread:  21  <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=1804)>

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000032, 0x0000000124718000

VM Regions Near 0x124718000:
    Stack                  0000000124696000-0000000124718000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 22
--> mapped file            0000000124718000-00000001247fd000 [  916K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
    CG shared images       00000001c0003000-00000001c000b000 [   32K] r--/r-- SM=SHM  

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B130a

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1aca1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1abd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba8155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba7779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba70b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8e776a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8e7767b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8e7765bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8145a3de _DPSNextEvent + 1434
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81459a2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x00000001067a3e31 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 84
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8144db2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81438913 NSApplicationMain + 940
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8dda55fd start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b1662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff88b8543d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff88b85152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddccf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddccf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1aca1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1abd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba8155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba7779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba70b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87db8967 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87db876b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1aca1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1abd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba8155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba7779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba70b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x00000001109fb40e -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 162
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87db876b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b09aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87bf3b83 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1aca1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1abd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba8155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba7779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba70b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87dbaadc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87ea34aa -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x0000000112ab0e0d -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87db876b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcdc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8d2d1a38 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 656
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8d2d178f startIOThread(void*) + 147
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddccf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddccf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1aca1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1abd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba8155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba7779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba70b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff815fa16e _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddccf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddccf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcdc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010c476363 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 524
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87db876b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcdc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010c476363 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 524
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87db876b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcdc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010c476363 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 524
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87db876b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: <lldb.comm.debugger.input>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b09aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d965f0 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 888
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d96052 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 170
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d94493 lldb_private::Communication::ReadFromConnection(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 97
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d940f1 lldb_private::Communication::ReadThread(void*) + 147
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: <lldb.comm.xcode.lldb.comm>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b09aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d965f0 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 888
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d96052 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 170
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d94493 lldb_private::Communication::ReadFromConnection(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 97
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d940f1 lldb_private::Communication::ReadThread(void*) + 147
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1aca1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1abd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba8155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba7779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ba70b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87c5c811 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff834007e3 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 355
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 20:: <lldb.process.gdb-remote.async>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcdc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e37697 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e81752 lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 90
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113dadcb4 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 324
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113daddcb lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e8bb51 ProcessGDBRemote::AsyncThread(void*) + 1213
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 21 Crashed:: <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=1804)>
0   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d98990 lldb_private::DataExtractor::GetU32(unsigned long long*) const + 52
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e73045 ObjectFileMachO::ParseHeader() + 91
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e724fd ObjectFileMachO::CreateInstance(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::DataBuffer>&, unsigned long long, lldb_private::FileSpec const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 661
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113ee9ac5 lldb_private::ObjectFile::FindPlugin(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&, lldb_private::FileSpec const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::DataBuffer>&, unsigned long long&) + 1705
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e6bf43 ObjectContainerUniversalMachO::GetObjectFile(lldb_private::FileSpec const*) + 427
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113ee9bd7 lldb_private::ObjectFile::FindPlugin(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&, lldb_private::FileSpec const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::DataBuffer>&, unsigned long long&) + 1979
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113ddafbc lldb_private::Module::GetObjectFile() + 210
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113dde60f lldb_private::ModuleList::GetSharedModule(lldb_private::ModuleSpec const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module>&, lldb_private::FileSpecList const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module>*, bool*, bool) + 805
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113f274d9 lldb_private::Target::GetSharedModule(lldb_private::ModuleSpec const&, lldb_private::Error*) + 543
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e64879 DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::FindTargetModuleForDYLDImageInfo(DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::DYLDImageInfo&, bool, bool*) + 391
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e6699f DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::AddModulesUsingImageInfos(std::__1::vector<DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::DYLDImageInfo, std::__1::allocator<DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::DYLDImageInfo> >&) + 487
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e65d7b DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::AddModulesUsingImageInfosAddress(unsigned long long, unsigned int) + 165
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e65612 DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::InitializeFromAllImageInfos() + 154
13  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e65a0c DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::NotifyBreakpointHit(void*, lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 44
14  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d45d0f lldb_private::BreakpointOptions::InvokeCallback(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 43
15  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d43250 lldb_private::BreakpointLocation::InvokeCallback(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*) + 82
16  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d43889 lldb_private::BreakpointLocation::ShouldStop(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*) + 115
17  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113d44386 lldb_private::BreakpointLocationCollection::ShouldStop(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*) + 76
18  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113f22748 lldb_private::StopInfoBreakpoint::ShouldStopSynchronous(lldb_private::Event*) + 232
19  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113f319cf lldb_private::Thread::ShouldStop(lldb_private::Event*) + 653
20  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113f365a3 lldb_private::ThreadList::ShouldStop(lldb_private::Event*) + 339
21  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113f12485 lldb_private::Process::ShouldBroadcastEvent(lldb_private::Event*) + 375
22  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113f1048c lldb_private::Process::HandlePrivateEvent(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 356
23  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113f12ae7 lldb_private::Process::RunPrivateStateThread() + 507
24  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113f1262d lldb_private::Process::PrivateStateThread(void*) + 9
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 22:: DBGLLDBSessionThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1b0716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcdc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e37697 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113e81752 lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 90
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113dadcb4 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 324
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113daddcb lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112c6f995 lldb::SBListener::WaitForEvent(unsigned int, lldb::SBEvent&) + 203
7   com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x000000010981aa22 DBGLLDBSessionThread(void*) + 813
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb899 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcb72a _pthread_start + 137
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ddcffc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 21 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fe807c15fa0  rcx: 0x00000000000e4850  rdx: 0x00000000000e4850
  rdi: 0x00007fe807c15ff8  rsi: 0x0000000124690310  rbp: 0x0000000124690290  rsp: 0x0000000124690290
   r8: 0x0000000124718000   r9: 0x0000000000000004  r10: 0x0000000001555568  r11: 0x000000002fd20404
  r12: 0x0000000000001000  r13: 0x00007fe807c15fa0  r14: 0x00007fe807c15ff8  r15: 0x00000000000e4850
  rip: 0x0000000113d98990  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000124718000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

I've tried to repair permissions using the Disk Utility and also disabled Source Control in Xcode. The problem disappears if I simply delete the reference to SDL. For example the following program works initially, but crashes when I link the project to SDL:

```
// #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Switching back to 2.0.1 worked for me as a temporary fix. :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that SDL2 isn't properly signed. There's a ticket to fix the issue at https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2058.

When you spawn an application from Xcode 5 with lldb, Xcode loads a plugin that will inspect modules your application loads, presumably to give you insight into your program. Xcode is set up to crash if it reads from a page that is backed by an invalid signature. Because SDL2 isn't properly signed, when Xcode 5 attempts to examine the SDL2 library, it will read from an invalid page, and crash. You get a clue that this is happening by the following line in your crash report above:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
```

To see for yourself that SDL isn't properly signed, execute the following command from the folder where SDL2 resides:

```
$ codesign -vvvv SDL2 
SDL2: invalid signature (code or signature have been modified)
In architecture: x86_64
```

If you don't want to build your own version of SDL2 (the solution that's mentioned above), you can update the signature to make it correct:

```
$ codesign -f -s - SDL2 
SDL2: replacing existing signature
```

And to verify that the new signature is good:

```
$ codesign -vvvv SDL2
SDL2: valid on disk
SDL2: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Note that doing this as a workaround is risky from a security standpoint, as I'm not sure why the signature is invalid.

Comment: Thank you! (I liked this much better than recompiling.)

Comment: So is it a bug that this answer works or that the other one works? Or both? xcodebuild from the command line (per the other answer) builds an executable that runs fine--even with an invalid signature on the framework. The Xcode (6.0.1) GUI also builds fine w/ an invalid signature. It's the executable that's the problem tho (crashes on run in xcode and freezes my entire computer when run from the command line). Fixing the signature problem is obviously the best start. But there's still something wrong (or that I don't understand) with xCode.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. So much better than a full rebuild.

Comment: Still crashing for me on xcode 6.1, mac os 10.10.1. Tried both, recompile and resigning

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem using 2.0.2 (stable).  I downloaded the latest code (as of 3/13) and compiled the framework manually and it worked.

1. hg clone http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL
2. Compile the "Framework" target in Xcode/SDL/SDL.xcodeproj
3. Copy framework to /Library/Frameworks

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you! Any idea what's wrong with the supplied binaries?

Comment: Same problem with version 2.0.3. This solution still works.  :-)

Comment: This worked.  Unbelievable.  Looks like there's a ticket for this though.  And it even references this question!  :)  https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2488

Comment: Could someone give steps on how to compile the Framework target? I downloaded the source directly from the SDL website, but thats as far as I got. Thank you!

I currently go around this by removing the LLDL debugger from the xcode schema since GDB is no longer supported, but I would rather have a debugger haha

Comment: Like so?   SDL$ xcodebuild -project Xcode/SDL/SDL.xcodeproj/ -target Framework

Comment: Is the downloaded framework maybe 32bit only? compiling the SDL.xcodeproj framework works now with my 64bit app.

Comment: This procedure worked, and I can confirm that the bug still exists in Xcode 5.1 and SDL 2.0.3

Comment: I build the framework but I don't know where the framework is being saved. Does anyone know where it would be?

Comment: It's a bit tricky, go to ~/Library and find . | grep SDL2.framework - e.g in my case I then did sudo cp -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL-aiuehmjgoyflvuahezmuiuyqjivz/Build/Products/Debug/SDL2.framework /Library/Frameworks/

Comment: This answer is fine, but I'm downvoting it and upvoting the `codesign` answer to shift attention. Resigning is much less painful than a full recompile.