# What can happen if I update code signature for SDL2?

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-mavericks, code-signing, sdl-2

I am a new user of macintosh and uses OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks. I have recently installed Xcode and I have downloaded SDL2. This is where the problems started.

When I tried to compile some code that uses SDL2, I got a Xcode crash. The crash was expected behaviors since the reason was an **invalid code signature** in SDL2.

So I googled this and 2 solutions came up in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368202/xcode-5-crashes-when-running-an-app-with-sdl-2). The first solution recommended that I downloaded the source code for SDL2 and recompiled it. The second solution was to update the code signature as

```
codesign -f -s - ~/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/SDL2
```

The second solution seems to be the preferred one since the first solution probably does this in the end anyway. However, I am not completely familiar with code signatures since I come from a windows environment (where these things are hidden for the most) and also since all programming I have done have been for internal use only. So this is the long introduction and my questions are then:

**Where is the code signature located (inside the frameworks or somewhere else in the computer)?**

**What can happen if I update the code signature? Especially can this cause any trouble in the future and even if SDL2.framework is uninstalled?**

BR Patrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not required to code sign a framework you build and install yourself (this is what I do for SDL 2). When Frameworks are codesigned the signature can be found in the "Versions" subdirectory of the Framework bundle. there will be the usual _CodeSignature directory for each signed "version", just as there is for an "app" bundle.

resigning the framework wont affect anything in your system. when you update the SDL2 framework to a version that doesnt have this problem your changes will be "undone".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So there in no risk then?

Comment: @patrik none that I can think of. even if it did affect something, it could be easily undone by reinstalling SDL2.