# How do I Compile a Framework in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, crash, sdl, sdl-2

Ever since I switched to Yosemite, I have been getting an Xcode quit unexpectedly error whenever I try to run SDL2.  I can't even get a "hello world" to run. 
I am trying the fix it by following the directions on this page:

[Xcode 5 crashes when running an app with SDL 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368202/xcode-5-crashes-when-running-an-app-with-sdl-2)

But I don't know how to "Compile the "Framework" target in Xcode/SDL/SDL.xcodeproj"  I tried just simply building it but that doesn't seem to work because I don't see any framework file showing up.

Can someone help me figure out how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have got the latest version of the code either by doing `hg clone http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL` or by downloading the latest snapshot from https://www.libsdl.org/hg.php

This should give you a directory called SDL which contains the source and all of the projects. You will want to open 'Xcode/SDL/SDL.xcodeproj'

Then ensure the following is set as your build target - **Framework > My Mac (64-bit)** You can change it by clicking on it.

[image]

Then hit CMD+B (or select Product->Build from the menu) to build the framework. You will then be able to find the `SDL2.framework` in the following location:

`/Users/*yourusername*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL2-*randomstring*/Build/Products/<*Debug/Release*>`

Copy the framework to `/Library/Frameworks`