# Profiling an executable containing the SDL framework doesn't work in Instruments

Tags: c++, profiling, sdl, instruments

I am unable to run OS X Instruments profiling on an SDL application. Seems like including the SDL2 framework during linking breaks the profiling. While normally I would get at least some meaningful stacks and a possibility to give symbols, now I get this. I can't see the application in the "Symbols..." view and the stack trace gives nothing meaningful. Leaving out the SDL2 framework fixes the issue. I haven't tried with older versions of SDL. I have tried linking with both clang and g++ with the same result.

[image: broken profiling]

What does the SDL2 framework do so it breaks the profiling? Can I get around this issue somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out SDL2 has a problem with signing. [This reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368202/xcode-5-crashes-when-running-an-app-with-sdl-2) explains more about it. Turns out it also affects profiling.